# Nullcheck multi level object

Tags: c#

I'v been playing around with some shorter hand ways of checking multiple nested objects to see if any are null before proceeding. I'm trying to replace the multiple nested if statements into a single statement if possible using Null-conditional Operators.

So far i have something like this:

```
if ((Object1?.Object2?.Object3?.Object4 != null) ? true : false)
{
...
}
```

Would the above be effective at identifying if either Object1 2 3 or 4 is null and return a false if so? I'm interested to hear if anyone has any better solutions?

TIA

Comment: The ' ? true : false' isn't needed

Comment: using the syntax in this way is ok, but a design that requires you to do this for so many levels is problematic.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to return false or true - boolean condition itself has boolean value:

```
if (Object1?.Object2?.Object3?.Object4 != null)
```

This part is a completely valid option for checking nested objects if any of them is null. You can find exactly same example in [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) documentation:

```
// null if customers, the first customer, or Orders is null  
int? count = customers?[0]?.Orders?.Count();
```

And explanation:

> The last example demonstrates that the null-condition operators are
>   *short-circuiting*. If one operation in a chain of conditional member
>   access and index operation returns null, then the rest of the chain’s
>   execution stops.

Comment: So this will evaluate to true only if all object are NOT null? And would not throw and exception if say Object2 is null?

Comment: @Nugs yes, exactly

Comment: @Nugs Correct that is the entire point of the `?.` operator. It only evaluates up to the first null it finds then it returns a `default(Object4Type)` (or a `default(Nullable<Object4Type>)` if `Object4Type` is a struct) to be compared against  `!= null`.

Comment: Awesome, i figured i was on the right track but wanted to confirm and get a better understanding of how best to use Null-conditional Operators for this purpose. I appreciate the quick lesson and confirmation guys! Thx

Comment: And make sure to thank the C# team for this one. The null-safe dot operator is a fairly recent addition to the language spec with C# 6, released alongside .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2015. Prior to that, the best solution was an extension method that looked like `Object1.OrDefault(o=>o.Object2.Object3.Object4)`, and basically wrapped a try-catch block that tried to evaluate the lambda, catching any `NullReferenceException`s or `InvalidOperationException`s and returning null in those situations. The null-safe dot is *much* cleaner.

Comment: @KeithS well... frankly speaking, this feature encourages developers to violate [law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and write code which is hard to test. If you are talking to `Object1.Object2.Object3.Object4` of method parameter or class property named `Object1`, it will be a pain to create chain of these mocks.

Comment: Well, the LoD, and any other design rules, are secondary to the function's primary purpose. Binding form data, for instance, can often require traversing three or more levels just to get the information for one group of controls, if the data layer (and thus your EF-mapped domain model) is highly normalized. Validation is similar; you may have a rule that applies across an entire graph, but requires traversing a sub-sub-sub-property of multiple child items to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
public void Foo()
{
    if ((Object1?.Object2?.Object3?.Object4 != null) ? true : false)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

is logically equivalent to

```
public void Foo()
{
    if ((NullCheck(Object1) != null) ? true : false)
    {
    ...
    }
}

private Object4Type NullCheck(Object1Type object1)
{
    if(!Object.RefrenceEquals(object1, null)) //This is "Object1?."
    {
        var tmpObject2 = tmpObject1.Object2;
        if(!Object.RefrenceEquals(tmpObject2, null)) //This is "Object2?."
        {
            var tmpObject3 = tmpObject2.Object3;
            if(!Object.RefrenceEquals(tmpObject3, null)) //This is "Object3?."
            {
                return tmpObject3.Object4;
            }        
        }
    }
    return default(Object4Type);
}
```

or if Object4Type is a struct

```
public void Foo()
{
    if ((NullCheck(Object1) != null) ? true : false)
    {
    ...
    }
}

private Nullable<Object4Type> NullCheck(Object1Type object1)
{
    if(!Object.RefrenceEquals(object1, null)) //This is "Object1?."
    {
        var tmpObject2 = tmpObject1.Object2;
        if(!Object.RefrenceEquals(tmpObject2, null)) //This is "Object2?."
        {
            var tmpObject3 = tmpObject2.Object3;
            if(!Object.RefrenceEquals(tmpObject3, null)) //This is "Object3?."
            {
                return tmpObject3.Object4;
            }        
        }
    }
    return default(Nullable<Object4Type>);
}
```

So your `...` will only be run if all objects are not null and if a lower level object is null, the later objects never get evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is currently the best way to do exactly what you want. I wanted to answer in order to illustrate what's necessary if you don't have access to the latest C# 6 language features. This is the next most developer-friendly way to make the same check in .NET 3.5-4.0:

```
    //boilerplate, off in your extension method library
    public static TOut OrDefault<TIn, TOut>(this TIn input, 
        Func<TIn, TOut> possiblyNullFunc)
    {
        try { return possiblyNullFunc(input); }
        catch (NullReferenceException) //for most reference types
        { return default(TOut); }
        catch (InvalidOperationException) //for Nullable<T>
        { return default(TOut); }
    }

    ...

    //usage
    if (Object1.OrDefault(o=>o.Object2.Object3.Object4) != null)
    {
        ...
    }
```

It functions pretty well, until you try to use `InvalidOperationException` in your own classes for situations other than null member access.

Still beats the pants off this, especially if you have to make this check a lot:

```
if(Object1 != null
    && Object1.Object2 != null
    && Object1.Object2.Object3 != null
    && Object1.Object2.Object3.Object4 != null)
{
    ...
}
```